# EF Core 3.1 one-to-zero relationship

Tags: sql-server, ef-core-3.1

Entities

```
Person
    INT Id
    Address Adresss

Address
    INT Id
    INT PersonId
```

Model Builder

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasOne(p => p.Address)
    .WithOne()
    .IsRequired(false)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
    .HasForeignKey<Adresss>(a => a.PersonId)
    .IsRequired();
```

When Id do this

```
Person.Address = null
```

and then save changes. I get this error

> The association between entity types 'Person' and 'Address' has been severed but the relationship is either marked as 'Required' or is implicitly required because the foreign key is not nullable.

I think the error is telling me to make `PersonId` (the foreign key) optional. So like below. Which is will result in the foreign key column being nullable in the SQL Server database.
What I want is to allow for a user to delete an Address but if an address is added then it must contain a PersonId. So I don't want this to be null

```
Address
    INT Id
    INT? PersonId
```

Can make I make personId in the address table not null but also allow person's address property to be optional? in other words one to one OR one to zero relationship

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best way to null Address is this:

`Context.Address.Remove(Person.Address)`

because Address is a DbSet, not only a navigation property. You have to mark the entity "Address" to be removed.

Comment: Thanks. That will work. But I have an issue with it. particularly from a DDD perspective 

The person entity could have a method. In this case it would be 
void Person.RemoveAddress()

And this method can choose to mutate the entity and its children in anyway it chooses, without the application layer (think asp controller here) knowing whats actually been mutated.
This solution Context.Address.Remove(Person.Address) moves logical out of the domain layer and into the application layer - which is not ideal
I wonder if EFCore can be configured to do give the exact behavior I want

Comment: Exposing the Person object, which is a DbSet, to the Controller, it's not recommendable. Maybe you can use Services or Repositories , part of the Domain layer, that "knows" the database structure

Comment: The issue would be the same for services as the service would be in the application layer too. Domain knowledge would leak from the entity to the service.
EF core is the repository. As an ORM its responsible for mapping my entities to the database. Ideally, I don't want to another repository wrapper to make up for the way I want it to map.

Comment: The domain layer shouldn't have any knowledge about DBSets or DB structure or DB implementation details

Comment: @PaulMcTigue *" As an ORM its responsible for mapping my entities to the database"* No, it's not. It is responsible for mapping **data** entity model, while yours is **domain** entity model. These are different. The way you put requirements for the domain made, the same way ORM puts some requirements on the data model. If these conflict, then create two entity models and map between where needed. Yes, this is a lot more code to write with probably a lot of duplication, but that's the cost of being pure. It's ok to follow some principles, but you can't expect other systems to do so .

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks. EF core has change tracking internal to it. Which is what makes it very appealing. I agree you can't be pure all the time when using ORMs, EF core included. However, because the relationship I described is a common one, I'd assumed that this would be handled by the change tracking. And that I hadn't configured it correctly in the model builder. i.e. person.address = null  would result in EF core figuring out that the address should be deleted

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/explicit-tracking
talks about deleting entities via change tracking by the way IvanStoev and AlbertoZ describe.
Both, Thanks for your help